# Creating a list in R from 2 vectors

Tags: r, list

I have a problem when I try to create a list in R. I have 2 vectors

```
a <- c(1:7)
b <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C")
```

The second vector (b) is an ordered factor. I am trying to create a list that would have the following form:

```
[A]
1, 2

[B]
3, 4, 5

[C]
6, 7
```

ie. I want to put the elements of the first vector into a list with each block of the list corresponding to the factor level of the second vector. I hope I was clear enough, thank you

Comment: @Pascal argh!!! Not sure if worth posting.

Comment: @DavidArenburg  :) please keep the answer.

Comment: @Pascal K, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Seems you could just use `split` here

```
split(a, b)
# $A
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $B
# [1] 3 4 5
# 
# $C
# [1] 6 7
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The resulting list in question however, is ordered alphabetically according to the second column ( the one containing the factors). Is there a way to create a list using split() whose blocks are not ordered alphabetically? I checked ?split() and there is no option for ordered or not - ordered list. I want the order of the list to be the one I give the second column. Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't understand. What order? This is gives identical output to your desired output.